# MS Visual Code function picker dropdown list

Tags: python, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2017 on Windows for c# and vb
and also Visual Code on  my Mac for Python.

In the Windows VS when you open a .cs or a .vb file you
get a dropdownlist at the top of the page that lists
all the functions in the file - is there anything like that
in Visual Code? Perhaps an extension or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this extension supports what you want it's called [Code Outline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline). It creates a panel in the Explorer.

Note for some languages the following will work (doesn't work for all languages)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> on Windows OR
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> on Mac

Comment: installed it but cant see any difference?

Comment: @BenderRodriguez did you try running the Reload Window command? you said youre coding in python? it worked on mine https://imgur.com/a/pCxrC maybe I misunderstood the solution you're looking for?

Comment: It's a panel, which isn't as convenient as an always available dropdown list at the top of your editpanel, just like visual studio 20xx has. The outline takes too much space.